# esp8266 blink not building to esp-01

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I am trying the esp8266 esp-01, and did all it asked on the Arduino IDE side, but I am having problems compiling and building the blink example into the board

Using: FT232RL usb-ttl in the 3.3v configuration, two 1.6v (new) batteries to power the esp, and all the conections as indicated [here](http://www.arduinesp.com/arduinesp/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/TTL-to-ESP01-blink-ESP8266.jpg) (not using the led though).

when I hit (go) it compiles, but as it transfers both boards blink synchronously and I receive the following errors:

```
O sketch usa 219.479 bytes (50%) de espaço de armazenamento para programas. O máximo são 434.160 bytes.
Variáveis globais usam 31.172 bytes (38%) de memória dinâmica, deixando 50.748 bytes para variáveis locais. O máximo são 81.920 bytes.

error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

It looks to me as a newbie that it's trying to establish a link and failing. What could it be?

The configurations are default, programmer is "AVRISP MKII"

Comment: I have this exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Its so old im not realy shure if I did, but I remember oscilations on power suply ( on my case being powered by the laptop) caused most of my comunication problems. try powering from an external DC source like bateries. Only thing I remember is that it eventualy worked

Comment: I figured it out, the programmer board i purchased to flash firmware to the esp was not a programmer board. The seller mislabelled it...it's just a "usb to serial interface" nad therefore does not put the ESP into flash mode. it took hours to figure that out.